# using multiple keyframes on multiple images

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to get the keyframes to work for each image. So I actually want one image to go to the left, and the other to the right. But when I run this code, it just uses the keyframes exactly the same for both pictures. I cannot seem to make two different paths for the two different images.

How would I go on about fixing this?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="funnel.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>

    <style>
        .Gurl1 {
            position: relative;
            padding-left: 500px;
        }    
        .Gurl2 {
            position: relative;
            padding-left: 300px;
        }   

        #girl2 {
            position: relative;
            margin-left: 10cm;
        }

        .center {
        margin: auto;
        width: 20%;
        border: 3px solid green;
        padding: 10px;

        }
    </style>
    </head>
        <body>

        <p><strong>Note:</strong> The animation-timing-function property is not supported in Internet Explorer 9 and earlier versions.</p>

        <div class="container">

        </div>

    <div class="funnel leads estimated">
      <h2 class="center-text">Actual 100 Day Lead Conversion</h2>
      <ul class="two">
        <li>
          <div class="funnel-top"></div>
          1574<span>Contacts</span>
        </li>
        <li>203<span>MQL2</span></li>
        <li>112<span>MQL2</span></li>
        <li>57<span>SAL</span></li>
        <li>11<span>SQL</span></li>
        <li>
          <div class="funnel-bottom"></div>
          4<span>Wins</span>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>


            <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-6 Gurl1"><h1>Girl1</h1></div>
            <div class="col-sm-9 col-md-6 Gurl2"><h1>Girl2</h1></div>

        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
          <script>
         $(function {
      $('').each(function(i) {
        $(this).delay(i*600).fadeIn('slow')
      });
        </script>
        <script>
        $( document ).ready(function() {
        $('head').append("<style> #girl2 {background-color: none;font-weight: bold;position: relative;-webkit-animation: mymove 5s infinite; animation: mymove 5s 1;animation-fill-mode: forwards;</style>                                                                                                                                                    <style> #div1 {animation-timing-function: linear;} #div2 {animation-timing-function: ease;}</style><style>@keyframes mymove {0% {top:0px; left:0px;} 25% {top:0px; left: 900px;} 50%  {top: 700px; left: 900px;} 100%  {top: 700px; left: 0px;} }</style>")

        $('.container').append("<img class='div2' id='girl1' src='http://www.returnofkings.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/prettygirl.jpg' height=auto width=80px/>                                                            <img id='girl2' class='div2' src='https://i.pinimg.com/736x/62/b8/6a/62b86a59e23510f5f6e48c5d899782c3--beautiful-people-beautiful-women.jpg' height=auto width=80px/>");
        });

        </script>


    </body>
    </html>
```

Here's the CSS for the FUNNEL if anyone's interested, although i found in on I think Codepen:

```
.center-text{
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0px auto;
}
.funnel{
  width:750px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

ul.one { 
    margin: 40px 278px; padding: 0; 
    list-style: none; 
    text-align: center;
}
.one .funnel-top {
    position: absolute;
    top: -7px;
    left: -199px;
    z-index: 20;
    width: 599px;
    height: 14px;
    background: #919eb1;
    border-radius: 100%;
}
.one .funnel-bottom {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -7px;
    left: -20px;
    z-index: 20;
    width: 240px;
    height: 16px;
    background: #273445;
    border-radius: 100%;
}

.one li {
    font-size:16px;
    line-height:70px;
    height:70px;
    width:200px;
    position:relative;
    background:#ccc;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.one li span {
  background: rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
  padding: 5px 8px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin-left: 15px;
}

.one li:before { 
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 10;
    left: 0%;
    margin-left: -30px;
    width:30px;
    border-top: 70px solid #ccc;
    border-left: 30px solid transparent;
}
.one li:after { 
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 10;
    right: 0%;
    margin-left: 30px;
    width:30px;
    border-top: 70px solid #ccc;
    border-right: 30px solid transparent;
}

.one li:nth-child(1) { background:#919eb1; }
.one li:nth-child(1):before,
.one li:nth-child(1):after { border-top-color:#919eb1; }
.one li:nth-child(1):before { width:200px; margin-left: -200px; }
.one li:nth-child(1):after  { width:200px; margin-right:-200px; }

.one li:nth-child(2) { background:#8491a5; }
.one li:nth-child(2):before,.one li:nth-child(2):after { border-top-color:#8491a5;}
.one li:nth-child(2):before { width:170px; margin-left: -170px; }
.one li:nth-child(2):after  { width:170px; margin-right:-170px; }

.one li:nth-child(3) { background:#778599; }
.one li:nth-child(3):before,
.one li:nth-child(3):after { border-top-color:#778599; }
.one li:nth-child(3):before { width:140px; margin-left: -140px; }
.one li:nth-child(3):after  { width:140px; margin-right:-140px; }

.one li:nth-child(4) { background:#6d7b8f; }
.one li:nth-child(4):before,
.one li:nth-child(4):after { border-top-color:#6d7b8f; }
.one li:nth-child(4):before { width:110px; margin-left: -110px; }
.one li:nth-child(4):after  { width:110px; margin-right:-110px; }

.one li:nth-child(5) { background:#606f84; }
.one li:nth-child(5):before,
.one li:nth-child(5):after { border-top-color:#606f84; }
.one li:nth-child(5):before { width:80px; margin-left: -80px; }
.one li:nth-child(5):after  { width:80px; margin-right:-80px; }

.one li:nth-child(6) { background:#536075; }
.one li:nth-child(6):before,
.one li:nth-child(6):after { border-top-color:#536075; }
.one li:nth-child(6):before { width:50px; margin-left: -50px; }
.one li:nth-child(6):after  { width:50px; margin-right:-50px; }



ul.two { 
    margin: 40px 278px; padding: 0; 
    list-style: none; 
    text-align: center;
}
.two .funnel-top {
    position: absolute;
    top: -7px;
    left: -199px;
    z-index: 20;
    width: 599px;
    height: 14px;
    background: #1b99e6;
    border-radius: 100%;
}
.two .funnel-bottom {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -7px;
    left: -20px;
    z-index: 20;
    width: 240px;
    height: 16px;
    background: #003352;
    border-radius: 100%;
}

.two li {
    font-size:16px;
    line-height:70px;
    height:70px;
    width:200px;
    position:relative;
    background:#ccc;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.two li span {
  background: rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
  padding: 5px 8px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin-left: 15px;
}

.two li:before { 
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 10;
    left: 0%;
    margin-left: -30px;
    width:30px;
    border-top: 70px solid #ccc;
    border-left: 30px solid transparent;
}
.two li:after { 
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 10;
    right: 0%;
    margin-left: 30px;
    width:30px;
    border-top: 70px solid #ccc;
    border-right: 30px solid transparent;
}

.two li:nth-child(1) { background:#1b99e6; }
.two li:nth-child(1):before,
.two li:nth-child(1):after { border-top-color:#1b99e6; }
.two li:nth-child(1):before { width:200px; margin-left: -200px; }
.two li:nth-child(1):after  { width:200px; margin-right:-200px; }

.two li:nth-child(2) { background:#148ad3; }
.two li:nth-child(2):before,.two li:nth-child(2):after { border-top-color:#148ad3;}
.two li:nth-child(2):before { width:170px; margin-left: -170px; }
.two li:nth-child(2):after  { width:170px; margin-right:-170px; }

.two li:nth-child(3) { background:#117fc3; }
.two li:nth-child(3):before,
.two li:nth-child(3):after { border-top-color:#117fc3; }
.two li:nth-child(3):before { width:140px; margin-left: -140px; }
.two li:nth-child(3):after  { width:140px; margin-right:-140px; }

.two li:nth-child(4) { background:#0b75b6; }
.two li:nth-child(4):before,
.two li:nth-child(4):after { border-top-color:#0b75b6; }
.two li:nth-child(4):before { width:110px; margin-left: -110px; }
.two li:nth-child(4):after  { width:110px; margin-right:-110px; }

.two li:nth-child(5) { background:#006bac; }
.two li:nth-child(5):before,
.two li:nth-child(5):after { border-top-color:#006bac; }
.two li:nth-child(5):before { width:80px; margin-left: -80px; }
.two li:nth-child(5):after  { width:80px; margin-right:-80px; }

.two li:nth-child(6) { background:#005f98; }
.two li:nth-child(6):before,
.two li:nth-child(6):after { border-top-color:#005f98; }
.two li:nth-child(6):before { width:50px; margin-left: -50px; }
.two li:nth-child(6):after  { width:50px; margin-right:-50px; }
```

Comment: in your code, only one image is moving (which is normal, the second has no `animation` in its styles). By the way, only one animation (`@keyframes mymove`) is defined in your styles too, if you want a different animation for another image, you have to create another `keyframes` in the styles

Answer (score 0):

I see that no one answered you, that's quite simple so here it is. See my example, all you have to do is to create different keyframes with different names, and declare each animation with the one you want.

You can declare different timings or repetition parameters for each element when you declare the `animation` property.

```css
@keyframes leftToRight{
  0% {left: 0%;}
  100% {left: 100%;}
}
@keyframes rightToLeft{
  0% {right: 0%;}
  100% {right: 100%;}
}

#image_1{
  top: 45%;
  left: 0%;
  border: 1px solid red;
  animation: leftToRight 5s 1;
}

#image_2{
  top: 45%;
  right: 0%;
  border: 1px solid green;
  animation: rightToLeft 5s 1;
}

#image_3{
  top: 69%;
  right: 0%;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  animation: rightToLeft 3s 3;
}

html, body{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container{
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.image{
  position: absolute;
  width: 42px;
  height: 42px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="image_1" class="image">&nbsp;</div>
  <div id="image_2" class="image">&nbsp;</div>
  <div id="image_3" class="image">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```